# Грамотная форма числительного

Tags: числительные

Кажется, верно произносить

> Мир знает двух типов людей

вместо

> Мир знает два типа людей.

Правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Мир знает (В.п.) два типа людей.**

1) Правило:

Ряд числительных (**два, три, четыре и собирательные** числительные) могут выражать категорию **одушевленности-неодушевленности** при сочетании с существительными.

Для **одушевленных** сущ.  **форма В.п. совпадает с формой Р.п**.: встретил  (кого?) двух девушек, двух студентов, обоих всадников. Для **неодушевленных** сущ. **форма В.п. совпадает с формой И.п**.: прочитал (что?) две книги, отдыхал двое суток, купил оба стола.

2) Числительное ***два*** относится к неод. сущ. ***тип***, а не к одуш. сущ. ***люди***.

3) Пример: Эта забавная подборка покажет вам (В.п.) **два основных типа людей.**